# Spark Scala : Got error javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch! from AES GCM binary file decryption

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, encryption, cryptography

Hi I'm trying to decrypt the zip file using `sc.BinaryFiles`

Scala version 2.11.12
Spark version 2.3

Here is my code

```
val input_bin = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("file.csv.gz.enc")
val input_utf = input_bin.map{f => f._2}.collect()(0).open().readUTF()
val input_base64 =  Base64.decodeBase64(input_utf)

val GCM_NONCE_LENGTH = 12
val GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16
val key = keyToSpec("<key>", 32, "AES", "UTF-8", Some("SHA-256"))

val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
val nonce = input_base64.slice(0, GCM_NONCE_LENGTH)

val spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, nonce)
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec)
cipher.doFinal(input_base64)

def keyToSpec(key: String, keyLengthByte: Int, encryptAlgorithm: String,
                keyEncode:String = "UTF-8", digestMethod: Option[String] = Some("SHA-1")): SecretKeySpec = {
    //prepare key for encrypt/decrypt
    var keyBytes: Array[Byte] = key.getBytes(keyEncode)

    if (digestMethod.isDefined) {
      val sha: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestMethod.get)
      keyBytes = sha.digest(keyBytes)
      keyBytes = util.Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, keyLengthByte)
    }

    new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, encryptAlgorithm)
  }
```

And I found error

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:571)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1046)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:983)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
  ... 50 elided
```

The input file is quite big (around 2GB).

I'm not sure, I read file incorrectly or the decryption has something wrong.

I also have the Python version and this code is work fine for me

```
real_key = key
hash_key = SHA256.new()
hash_key.update(real_key)

for filename in os.listdir(kwargs['enc_path']):
    if (re.search("\d{12}.csv.gz.enc$", filename)) and (dec_date in filename):
        with open(os.path.join(kwargs['enc_path'], filename)) as f:
            content = f.read()
            f.close()
            ct = base64.b64decode(content)
            nonce, tag = ct[:12], ct[-16:]
            cipher = AES.new(hash_key.digest(), AES.MODE_GCM, nonce)
            dec = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ct[12:-16], tag)
            decrypted_data = gzip.decompress(dec).decode('utf-8')
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Update #1

I was able to resolved the problem, by change the file reading method from Spark to be local file reading (scala.io) and add the AAD for decryption also apply the answers from @Topaco and @blackbishop

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec)
cipher.updateAAD(Array[Byte]()) // AAD can be changed to be any value but must be exact the same value when file is encrypted
cipher.doFinal(input_base64.drop(12)) // drop nonce before decrypt
```

I'm still finding out, why Spark doesn't work

Comment: In `doFinal()` only _ciphertext|tag_ may be passed and not _nonce|ciphertext|tag_.

Comment: @Topaco Hi, Thank you for your response, I tried `cipher.doFinal(input_base64.slice(12, input_base64.length))` and `cipher.doFinal(input_base64, 12, input_base64.length - 12)` but still found same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the same decryption method as in Python. In the scala code, you are ignoring the tag and when you call `doFinal` you're passing all the cipher.

Try with these changes :

```
// specify the tag length when creating GCMParameterSpec
val spec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH, nonce)

// remove the nonce part from the cipher before calling doFinal
val dec = cipher.doFinal(input_base64.drop(GCM_NONCE_LENGTH))
```

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop I have tried your suggestion, still no luck. I edit some of your code GCM_TAG_LENGTH is Byte unit so I multiply by 8 to convert as Bit.

Comment: @Thananthip.S do you get the same error message `Tag mismatch!`?

Comment: @blackcishop yes, same error. I also change the reading way from spark to be `scala.io.Source.fromFile`, got `Tag mismatch` error

Comment: @Thananthip.S do you have an example of encrypted cipher and the expected output from decryption? I suspects that this line `input_bin.map{f => f._2}.collect()(0).open().readUTF()` does not the same thing as python `content = f.read()`

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue... if you resolved can you please post the code as ans. Thanks

Comment: @Minisha Hi, sorry for late reply. I added some code change in the question above. you can see at the update section. The changing is use empty array as AAD and apply the nonce dropping but do not drop tag from data